# How to get the list of all directories and subdirectories in a specified path using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

My directory structure is like below.

Parent directory 
---Sub directory 1
---Sub directory 2 
------Sub directory2a
------Sub directory2b
---Sub directory 3

I am writing in VB.net to fetch all the directory names (including sub directories in all the levels)

However while using directory.getfilesystementries(path) I am getting only the top level sub directories. Any idea on how to fetch all the subdirectory names of all sub levels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use something like this:

```
Dim result = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

the trick is the `SearchOption.AllDirectories`

BTW: you can do the same with your GetFileSystemEntries-Method

Comment: +1 Beat me by 2 minutes, with a different way to do it but the same key part (SearchOption.AllDirectories) :)

Comment: Thanks. I missed the searchoption part :-D

Answer (score 1):

The Directoryinfo object can provide all sorts of information and about a directory, including directories / Files even system files

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim dir As New DirectoryInfo("C:\")
    For Each dirItem As DirectoryInfo In dir.GetDirectories
        MsgBox(dirItem.Name)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim di As New DirectoryInfo(FolderName)
di = New DirectoryInfo(path)

rgFiles = di.GetFiles("*.*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)

For Each fi As FileInfo In rgFiles
    If CheckIfExist(fi.FullName.ToString.Replace("\" & fi.Name, "")) = False Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(fi.FullName.ToString.Replace("\" & fi.Name, ""))
    End If
Next

Public Function CheckIfExist(ByRef Path As String) As Boolean
    Dim RetVal As Boolean = False

    For Each LI As String In ListBox1.Items
        If LI.ToString = Path Then
            RetVal = True
            Return RetVal
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    Return RetVal
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the overloaded version of Directory.GetFileSystemEntries that specifies whether or not to search subdirectories:

```
Dim allDirectories As String() = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries("path", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

[Directory.GetFileSystemEntries Method (String, String, SearchOption)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383460.aspx)